# Slicing list by characters and elements, Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, slice

I have a text column of limited width, and each row is a list of multiple elements, delimited by by semicolons. I would like to remove all list elements that cause the row to pass the character limit.

Previously, I was using

```
   if len(row[7].split(';')) > 5:
        row[7] = ('; '.join(row[7].split(';')[1:5]).strip())[:45]
```

This creates two obvious problems:

- Some lists have fewer than 5 elements and more than 45 characters, so the conditional does not delete the extra elements like it should
- List elements get cut off mid-word.

This is an example input:

```
 Foo; Bar; Aoicsdeadwcwewrw; owierwicowmwoemow; aoweirwoer
 ODIFUWE
 acowierwe; asodicjwoer; s; ow; w; w
```

This is the corresponding example output:

```
 Foo; Bar; Aoicsdeadwcwewrw
 ODIFUWE
 acowierwe; asodicjwoer; s; ow; w
```

The limit is 5 elements or 45 characters, and if the line reaches either of these limits the trailing elements should be cut off.

Comment: Are you counting the semicolons and spaces in the 45 characters?

Comment: Also, what do you want to do if the first item in the list is more than 45 characters? Cut everything, resulting in an empty string?

Comment: Yes and Yes, good clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> data = """ Foo; Bar; Aoicsdeadwcwewrw; owierwicowmwoemow; aoweirwoer
...  ODIFUWE
...  acowierwe; asodicjwoer; s; ow; w; w""".split("\n")
>>> 
>>> for row in data:
...     row = row.split(";")[:5]
...     res = []
...     for item in row:
...         if len(";".join(res + [item])) > 45: break
...         res.append(item)
...     print ";".join(res)
... 
 Foo; Bar; Aoicsdeadwcwewrw
 ODIFUWE
 acowierwe; asodicjwoer; s; ow; w
```

Comment: Rather than repeatedly joining to get a string to test the length of, why not just use `+=` on your strings? You seem to be manually recreating the [Schlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html) that `str.join` is usually used to avoid.

Comment: @Blckknght, This is one literal interpretation of the requirements. It's fairly clear to see what's going on. Better to go for simple and correct if performance is not critical.

Answer (score 2):

I think this generator is the most efficient way to determine where to cut your list of strings:

```
def limit(iterable, max_num, max_length, padding_length):
    seen_length = -padding_length  # the first value will not be padded so start negative
    for i, s in enumerate(iterable, 1):
        if i > max_num or seen_length + padding_length + len(s) > max_length:
            return
        seen_length += padding_length + len(s)
        yield s
```

Use it like this:

```
row[7] = "; ".join(limit(row[7].split("; "), 5, 45, 2)
```

The generator doesn't join any strings, just adds their lengths together, so using it and one `join` will be `O(N+M)` where `N` is the number of strings and `M` is the length of the result string. This is better than `gnibbler`'s solution, which is `O(N*M)` due to repeated `join`s. This algorithmic improvement probably doesn't matter much for relatively short and few strings, like you describe, but if you were trying to limit things to say, 500 items and a length of thousands of characters, you'd probably notice the difference.

Comment: It's a bit more above my head, so it's nice to see both methods.  However, since I am using hundreds of thousands of items each in dozens of globbed CSVs, performance may be something to watch.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional breakdown, which should make it more obvious what is going on:

```
data = [
    " Foo; Bar; Aoicsdeadwcwewrw; owierwicowmwoemow; aoweirwoer",
    " ODIFUWE",
    " acowierwe; asodicjwoer; s; ow; w; w"
]

def first_n_chars(s, break_on, n):
    if len(s) > n:
        return s[:s.rfind(break_on, 0, n + len(break_on))]
    else:
        return s

def first_n_groups(s, break_on, n):
    try:
        end = -1
        for _ in range(n):
            end = s.index(break_on, end+1)
        return s[:end]
    except ValueError:
        return s

fortyfivechars = (first_n_chars (s, '; ', 45) for s in data)
fivegroups     = (first_n_groups(s, '; ', 5)  for s in fortyfivechars)
trimmed_data   = list(fivegroups)
```

which results in

```
[' Foo; Bar; Aoicsdeadwcwewrw',
 ' ODIFUWE',
 ' acowierwe; asodicjwoer; s; ow; w']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def myfilter(x, wmax=5, cmax=45, d=';'):
    words = x.split(d)

    nwords = 0
    nchars = 0
    s = []
    for i in words:
        nwords += 1
        nchars += len(i) + len(d)
        if (nwords >= wmax) | (nchars > cmax+1):
            break
        s.append(i)
    return ';'.join(s)
```

Something like this should work.